# Как преобразовать строку в массив типа int?

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Вот у меня есть строка и массив

```
String s[] = new String[5];
int num[] = new int [5];
```

Как преобразовать или записать строку в целочисленный массив не используя Integer.parseInt(s)?

Comment: может поможет это обсуждение: [Как конвертировать строку в число с ОО-языках][1] ?


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/252213/java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это учебная задача? Почему такое странное ограничение? Используйте [`new Integer(s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer%28java.lang.String%29).

---

Если совсем уж извращаться, можно попробовать распарсить вручную:

```
long result = 0;
boolean negative = false;
int i = 0, len = s.length();
if (len > 0 && s.charAt[0] == '-')
{
    negative = true;
    i = 1;
}
for (; i < len; i++)
{
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    int digit = (int)c - (int)'0';
    if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid digit: '" + c + "'");
    result = 10 * result + c;
    if (result > Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1) // подумайте, почему именно так
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Integer overflow");
}
if (negative)
    result = -result;
if (result > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Integer overflow");
return (int)result;
```

Comment: Я пробую самостоятельно изучить java, так что в какой - то мере это учебная задача. А ограничения нет, мне просто стало любопытно.

Comment: ну если в рамках любопытства, то можно придумать следующее решение, достойное лучших сынов из страны слонов и чая:  
  
    int crazy_int;    
    if("1".equals(""+1))    
        crazy_int=1;